# Need help building a VF page

Tags: visualforce

Need help in building a VF page which displays account - child object 1 records table in VF and one is selected or all selected need to display its child records that is child object 2 of child object 1.

Any example for it or any work around is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can take help from the below example. Here I have a list of accounts on the vf page, when i select any/multiple accounts, the selected accounts, and their related contacts are displayed in seperate sections.

vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="vkAccountClass">
<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="value1" rerender="abcd"/>
<apex:commandButton value="first" action="{!fstbtn}" onclick="value1();"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="PRE" action="{!prvbtn}" disabled="{!prv}" onclick="value1();"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="next" action="{!nextbtn}" onclick="value1();"/>
    <apex:pageblock title="Accounts" >
    <apex:pageblocksection id="abcd">
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!AccountList}" var="a" >
            <apex:column >
                <apex:inputcheckbox onclick="valueTransferOnSelected1();" value="{!a.selected}" selected="{!selectedAccounts}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!a.acc.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageblockTable>
        </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:pageblock>
<script>
    function valueTransferOnSelected(){
        alert(111);
    }
</script>
   <apex:actionFunction name="valueTransferOnSelected1" rerender="pb2"/>
    <apex:pageblock id="pb2" title="Realted Details and Contacts">
        <apex:pageblocksection title="Selected Account Details">
            <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:dataTable value="{!selectedAccounts}" var="s" bgcolor="lightyellow" columnsWidth="100px, 100px" title="Selected Accounts Details" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="2">
                    <apex:column title="Account Name"><apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet> {!s.Name}</apex:column>  
                    <apex:column title="Phone Number"><apex:facet name="header">Phone Number</apex:facet> {!s.Phone}</apex:column>
                    <apex:column title="Fax"><apex:facet name="header">Fax</apex:facet> {!s.Fax}</apex:column>
                    <apex:column title="Account Number"><apex:facet name="header">Account Number</apex:facet> {!s.AccountNumber}</apex:column>
                    <apex:column title="Annual Revenue"><apex:facet name="header">Annual Revenue</apex:facet> {!s.AnnualRevenue}</apex:column>
                </apex:dataTable>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageblockSection>

        <apex:pageblocksection title="Related Contacts Details" >
            <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:dataTable value="{!selectedContacts}" var="c" title="Related Contacts Details" bgcolor="lightyellow" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="7" border="2">
                    <apex:column title="Contact Name"><apex:facet name="header">Contact Name</apex:facet> {!c.Name}</apex:column>  
                    <apex:column title="Birthdate"><apex:facet name="header">Birthdate</apex:facet> {!c.Birthdate}</apex:column>
                    <apex:column title="Department"><apex:facet name="header">Department</apex:facet> {!c.Department}</apex:column>
                    <apex:column title="Lead Source"><apex:facet name="header">Lead Source</apex:facet> {!c.LeadSource}</apex:column>
                    <apex:column title="Contact Phone"><apex:facet name="header">Contact Phone</apex:facet> {!c.Phone}</apex:column>
                </apex:dataTable>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public with sharing class vkAccountClass 
{
  //public List<Account> accList {get; set;}
  public List<Id> AccountIds {get; set;}
  public integer counter = 0;
  //public List<Contact> selectedContacts {get; set; }
  public List<aAccount> AccountList {get; set;}



  public vkAccountClass()
  {
    AccountList  = new list<aAccount>();
    result();
  }
  public void result()
  {
    for(Account acc :  [SELECT Id, Name,Phone,Fax,AccountNumber, AnnualRevenue, (Select Id, Name, Birthdate, Department, LeadSource, Phone From Contacts)from Account LIMIT 3 OFFSET: counter])
    {
      AccountList.add(new aAccount(acc));
    }
  }

  public void nextbtn(){
    counter += 5 ;
    Result();}
  public void fstbtn(){
    counter = 0;
    Result();}
  public void prvbtn(){
    counter -= 5 ;
    Result();}
    public boolean getprv(){
    if(counter == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;}



  public List<Account> getselectedAccounts()
  {
    system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+AccountList);  
    AccountIds= new List<Id>();
    list<Account>selectedAccounts = new List<Account>();
    for(aAccount ac : AccountList)
    {
      if(ac.selected != false)
      {
        selectedAccounts.add(ac.acc);
        // checkbox checked accounts added to selectedAccounts List
        AccountIds.add(ac.acc.id);
        // Id's of selected accounts obtained
      }
    }
    return selectedAccounts;
  }
  // selected accounts

  // related contacts of selected Accounts
  public List<Contact> getselectedContacts()
  {
    system.debug('###########'+AccountList);
    list<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();
    selectedContacts = [SELECT Name, Birthdate, Department, LeadSource, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Account.Id IN : (AccountIds)];
    return selectedContacts;
  }




  // wrapper controller class
  public class aAccount
  {
    public Account acc{get; set;}
    public boolean selected {get; set;}

    public aAccount(Account a)
    {
      selected = false;
      acc = a;
    }
  }

  public void getSelected(){

  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.